# Select cells between first blank row and third blank row, then paste into another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, select, resize, row

I am trying to make a subroutine that selects the rows between the first blank row and the third blank row and moves it (while deleting it from the original sheet) into a sheet labeled "Hold or Cancelled"

I have a blank row function that basically looks for the first blank cell in column E, then selects that row. I have tried playing arrow with Selection.Resize but cannot seem to get it working.

```
Dim i1 As Long
Dim i2 As Long
Dim i3 As Long
i1 = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
i2 = .Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 3
i3 = i2 - i1

ActiveSheet.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Resize (i3)
```

I have no clue how to move the selection into the other sheet.

Comment: You dont need to use Select at all, and it is not recommended to use it inside VBA, for copying operations or other. Better not think about it, and focus on well identifiying your source Range, your destination Range, and using sourceRange.copy destinationRange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways to move rows between sheets

Suppose you want to move rows with empty cells in column E, from "Sheet1" to "Sheet2"

[image: MoveRows.png]

---

To move one row at the time

```
Public Sub moveRows1()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, xRow1 As Long, xRow2 As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    xRow1 = ws1.Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Row       'find 1st blank cell on Sheet1
    xRow2 = ws2.UsedRange.Row + ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count    'find 1st blank cell on Sheet2

    ws1.Rows(xRow1).Cut                     'cut entire row from Sheet1
    ws2.Rows(xRow2).Insert Shift:=xlDown    'paste it on Sheet2
    ws1.Rows(xRow1).Delete Shift:=xlUp      'remove empty row from Sheet1
    'ws1.Rows(xRow1).EntireRow.Delete       'or delete entire row
End Sub
```

---

All rows at once

```
Public Sub moveRows2()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ur1 As Range, xRow2 As Long

    Set ws1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    xRow2 = ws2.UsedRange.Row + ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count    'find 1st blank cell on Sheet2

    Set ur1 = ws1.UsedRange

    With ur1
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="="       'AutoFilter Col E (blank cells)

        'If there are any visible rows
        If ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, ur1.Column).End(xlUp).Row > ur1.Row Then

            'Copy-paste visible data from Sheet1 to Sheet2
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Copy ws2.Cells(xRow2, 1)

            'Delete visible range with data from Sheet1
            .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).EntireRow.Delete

        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```